# Using WebClient with x509 certificate returns 403

Tags: c#, ssl, https, webclient, x509

I have a certificate registered in the certificate storage, can go to the website that requires this certificate and it 'logs in' just fine with the certificate. I am trying to do the same in code.

The certificate loads correctly from the storage, but I still get a 403 (Forbidding) when trying to get the website in question. Any ideas why?

Here is the code.

First getting the certificate:

```
    public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        const string certStore = "CurrentUser";

        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

        bool found = false;
        string certsFound = "";

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certCollection)
        {
            certsFound += cert.SubjectName.Name + Environment.NewLine;
            certificate = cert;

            if (cert.Subject.Contains("CertProviderName"))
            {
                found = true;

                break;
            }

        }

        if (!found)
            throw new ApplicationException("Certificate not found!" + Environment.NewLine + "Certs found: " +
                                           certsFound + Environment.NewLine + "CertStore=" + certStore);

        return certificate;
    }
```

Creating a custom webclient:

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    public X509Certificate2 Certificate { get; set; }
    public readonly CookieContainer CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(address);

        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;

        request.ClientCertificates.Add(Certificate);

        return request;
    }

}
```

...and try to access website:

```
    public static void GetPage()
    {
        var cert = GetCertificate();

        var client = new MyWebClient();
        client.Certificate = cert;

        var page = client.DownloadString(@"https://the.website.com");
    }
```

It fails on "client.DownloadString" with a 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: If you are using IIS as the web server you can look in the IIS logs for the subcode.  This will shed more light onto a service side validation problem.  It could also be a client side rejection.  Providing your own implementation of System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback will shed more light on that.  The most common client side error is that the server cert does not have the proper CN for the listening URL.  In your example it must be CN=the.website.com.